# EMC/EMI tests should be applied to power transformers or not?

Tags: transformer, emc, electromagnetic

I'm currently working in a naval industry. I see that EMC/EMI tests aren't applied to many of the transformers in combat ships. I wonder, is there any logical reason or explanation for this? I also searched that "Is it logical to apply EMC/EMI tests for transformers?" ; however, I couldn't get any rational answer.

I also consulted this situation to my colleagues working in different military industries. Result is the same, they also didn't apply EMC/EMI tests to transformers but they don't know why it is.

Comment: They aren’t sources of EMI to start with?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that power transformers won't suffer from electromagnetic interference from other devices. The opposite may be false, but perhaps, because they only emit fields at low frequency (operating frequency), they end up 'going unnoticed' in these tests. Furthermore, most transformers end up confined in a 'Faraday's cage'.

Comment: @LuizOliveira the transformer is not much of an emitter. But the evanescent field at 50 Hz to 400 Hz may extend for a long way. I am not aware of any EMI standards that would apply to transformers in general, though.

Comment: @mkeith exactly, the ~50Hz field intentionally emitted by the naval ELF transmitter (basically the antenna is Michigan's Upper Peninsula) is intended to reach submarines deep at sea around the world.

Answer (score 1):

The Navy probably is allowed to make its own rules regarding electromagnetic compatibility (EMC). I know that military bases in the US have their own local authority and are not subject to FCC regulations for emissions which do not exit the base.

However, just for enlightenment, the FCC sets limits on conducted and/or radiated emissions in the range of 9 kHz to 3000 GHz. The transformer, assuming it is operating at some low frequency (such as 50 Hz, 60 Hz, or 400 Hz) would not ITSELF be a source of unwanted emissions (whether radiated or conducted) from 9 kHz to 3000 GHz.

My thought is that in the civilian world, in the US, transformers are simply not radio frequency devices at all (from the perspective of the FCC), or if they are, they are considered "incidental radiators," and therefore not subject to testing and verification. Basically it is assumed that they are free of objectionable emissions, unless someone discovers a problem, in which case the owner of the transformer would have to take corrective action, I guess.

Of course, a device powered by a transformer could inject noise into the AC power line and cause the transformer to participate in objectionable emissions. But that issue would likely be resolved by modifying the device or adding a filter on the power line, not by modifying the transformer itself. The transformer really has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's handled under a different bailiwick (department).  And/or "above your pay grade" and possibly even "you're not cleared for that".

EMC/EMI is a gigantic, huge, very big deal to naval ships, because it's combat-relevant.  You wouldn't think surface ships are stealth, but they are. They don't want the enemy finding the ship from its EM emission.  So it's very closely surveilled and tested *on a whole-ship basis*. The Navy will not accept the ship until they've tested it thoroughly.

In fact they have a material condition called EMCON (Emission Control) which is NO intended external emissions. Watch the series *The Last Ship* and it's prominently discussed, and becomes a plot point in episode 1-2.

Comment: A bit more on what Harper said.  EMI/EMC requirements are usually levied on a system, or subsystem, or an assembly, and not on the individual things that make that up that system, subsystem, or assembly.  Within a given assembly there needs to be an assessment done for self-compatibility, which simple means that part A should not cause part B to malfunction, or vice versa.  But that almost never rises to the level of testing Part A against an EMC requirement.